# How to change the border style of a huxtable?

Tags: r, border, huxtable

I am trying to set the right border of col = 1 of my huxtable. I can get the border to appear, but it remains "dashed" despite my attempts to change it to "solid".

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(huxtable)

set.seed(72723)

df <- data.frame(ID = sample(c(1:30), 200, replace = TRUE),
                 Day = sample(seq(2, 16, 2), 200, replace = TRUE),
                 Treatment = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 200, replace = TRUE))

df <- df[order(df$Treatment, df$ID, df$Day), ]
df <- df %>% distinct(ID, Day, .keep_all = TRUE)

out <- as_huxtable(table(df$Treatment, df$Day))

out
```

Raw huxtable:

[image: Raw huxtable]

Now, I want to set a bottom border under the values of Day and a right border next to the treatment values.

```
out %>% insert_row(rep(NA, length(out)), after = 0) %>%
  set_contents(row = 1, col = round(length(out)/2), value = "Day") %>%
  set_bottom_border(row = 2, col = everywhere) %>%
  set_right_border(row = everywhere, col = 1, brdr(style = "solid"))
```

The right border appears dashed:

[image: The right border appears dashed]

The right border appears dashed despite setting `brdr(style = "solid")`

I also try using `set_right_border_style(value = "solid)`:

```
out %>% insert_row(rep(NA, length(out)), after = 0) %>%
  set_contents(row = 1, col = round(length(out)/2), value = "Day") %>%
  set_bottom_border(row = 2, col = everywhere) %>%
  set_right_border(row = everywhere, col = 1) %>%
  set_right_border_style(row = everywhere, col = 1, value = "solid")
```

No change:

[image: No change]

How can I change this vertical border to the right of column 1 to be solid?

Comment: The two lower calls both create solid lines for me; `huxtable` version 5.5.2. Maybe this a package version issue? Try updating `huxtable`: `install.packages("huxtable")`

Comment: The issue is that when printing to screen the border styles are not shown. From the docs (`?print_screen`): `Cell padding, widths and heights are not shown, nor are border styles.`

Comment: @stefan Yes, this was the confusion. I was using in conjunction with Rmarkdown/Knitr, and after creating my html I can see that the line is solid.

Comment: It's also that some terminals put gaps between lines. Nothing huxtable can do about that....